# HTML/CSS: Start of DIV at an odd position

Tags: css

At this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/8e8h5acf/11/), why is `nav#nav-header-menu` starting at the top of the screen?

In the HTML, it starts after `div#header-right`.

The reason I ask is I'd like to move `nav#nav-header-menu` upwards (`margin-top: -2em;`) so that the logo sits between the two horizontal borders, like this:

[image]

The JSFiddle works best with a wide HTML window width.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="site-container">
    <header class="site-header" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
     <div class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="header-left">
            <p><a href="mailto:contact@vmpersonal.com" title="Email Us"><img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/email.png" alt="Email Us" title="Email Us"></a> <a href="mailto:contact@vmpersonal.com" title="Email Us">contact@vmpersonal.com</a> </p>
        </div>
        <div id="header-right">
            <p><span id="social"><a href="#" title="Watch us on YouTube"><img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/youtube.png" alt="Watch us on YouTube" title="Watch us on YouTube"></a> <a href="#" title="Follow us on Facebook"><img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/facebook.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook"></a> <a href="#" title="Follow us on Instagram"><img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/insta.png" alt="Follow us on Instagram" title="Follow us on Instagram"></a></span> <span id="user"><a ref="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-login.php" title="Sign In to VM Personal">Sign In</a> / <a href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-login.php?action=register" title="Register for an account on VM Personal">Register</a></span></p>
        </div>
        <nav id="nav-header-menu">
            <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
                <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="genesis-nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-104"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/" itemprop="url">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-109"><a href="/shop" itemprop="url">Products &amp; Services</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/blog/" itemprop="url">Blog</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-110" style="display: none;"><a href="/" itemprop="url">Logo</a></li><img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/logo.png" width="124px">
                    <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/success-stories/" itemprop="url">Success Stories</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/about/" itemprop="url">About</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/contact/" itemprop="url">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </nav>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/style.css">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/mhm-style.css">
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Add `.container {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadUsman, that helped, but the `nav#nav-header-menu` still starts at the top of the screen, which I don't understand.

Comment: You have some negative margin. Remove or reset it `#nav-header-menu {margin-top: 0}` as well.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman making the `margin-top: 0` does not move the `#nav-header-menu` - it stays in the same place, starting at the top of the page.

Comment: Yes, so you wants to move it up?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `div#header-right` has a `float` property set on it. When something is floated, it is taken out of the normal static rendering context of HTML, which renders one element after the other. Check out [Layouts with float and clear](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) here.

What you can try doing is taking the logo out of the `nav` container and making `header-left`, `header-right` and your logo all within the same container. Here's the general idea...what do you think?

```
<header class='container'>
    <div class='header-left'></div>
    <!-- put your logo here -->
    <div class='header-right'></div>
</header>
<nav class='container'>
    <div class='nav-items-left'></div>
    <div class='nav-spacer'></div>
    <div class='nav-items-right></div>
</nav>

header {
    max-height: /* desired height */;
    overflow: visible;
}

.header-left,
.header-right,
.your-logo,
.nav-items-left,
.nav-items-right,
.nav-spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.nav-spacer {
    width: /* same width as your logo */;
}
.your-logo {
    width: /* width of your logo */;
}
```